# Multilingual in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, internationalization, drupal-8, multilingual

We're starting our upgrade from D7 to D8. I have a general question about implementing a multilingual site, given we have limited resources and a tight timeline, and currently we do not have any multilingual content on our D7 site.

If we were to build our D8 site using only English, and then decide to implement multilingual functionality in the future, how much of a headache will it be to implement after the fact?

Are we better off to set up multilingual functionality now, and have it sitting there not doing anything, as is currently the case in our D7 site, or will it be just as easy for us to enable it in, say, 15 months, once the entire D7 site has been ported to D8? Would there be any disadvantage or pain points that we'd experience by doing it all in a phase 2 of this project, rather than enabling the multilingual modules, as described here - https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/multilingual/choosing-and-installing-multi....

Thanks,
Pablo

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be easier to add translations in Drupal 8. In 7 you will need to add several modules and translate in a manner that is easy to port (entity translation and not node translation).   8 is multilingual first so it is assumed you will translated content.   In 7 it is more of an afterthought.